# Django- filtering results where one or more reverse foreign keys meet criteria

Tags: django, filter, orm, foreign-keys

Lets say I have the following (simplified) models:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
​    
class JobDateStatus(models.Model)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=6)
```

Is there a way to select all `Job` objects where any (one or more) of its `JobDateStatus` children have a particular status?  e.g.:

```
active_jobs = Job.objects.filter(<ONE OR MORE OF jobdatestatus_set HAS status='active'>)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what the normal double-underscore syntax does.

```
Job.objects.filter(jobdatestatus__status='active')
```

Comment: doh!  I always seem to forget that you can use the non `_set` version of a relationship in a filter.  Thanks for the reminder!